# Github - How to commit my project to a sub-folder / directory of a existing repository?

Tags: github

In Github, i have already a repository, e.g. called "java8"

And under it, i would like to have a sub-folder, e.g. called "01-lambda"

So my folder structure in github should be

```
java8 
    01-lambda
    02-enums
    etc.
```

Then I want to commit my code to the sub-folder "01-lambda"

How can I do that?

What I tried:

1. I just created a new folder with a txt file "01-lambda" under the repository "java8", then I tried to commit, but git bash shows they cannot find the sub-file.
2. I just commit my code directly to repository "java8", but then I need to change path of every files, and add /01-lambda in the path

   git init
   git add *
   git commit -m “my first repo”
   git remote add github .git
   git remote -v
   git push -f github master

Comment: A folder is empty?

Comment: No, not empty, the first way i tried, a added a txt file to the sub-folder. The question is, how can i then commit the code into this sub-folder and then delete the txt file?

Answer (score 0):

> I just created a new folder with a txt file "01-lambda" under the repository "java8", then i tried to commit, but git bash shows they cannot find the sub-file.

You need to add before committing, assuming you do have a file inside the new folder (Git would not add just a folder):

```
git add 01-lambda
git commit -m "add 01-lambda"
```

Comment: Hi VonC, i tried your solution, but then i got the following message "fatal: pathspec '01-lambda' did not match any files".

Comment: For example, in this repository "https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-microservices", he has a repository called "spring-microservices
", then under this folder, there are sub-folders like "01.framework-introductions" etc. In Each Sub-Folder he commit the code. I also want to the folder structure like that, how??

Comment: @ZiSang Do you have a folder named `01-lambda` with a file in it? Do this `01-lambda` folder has a `.git` subfolder in it? (it should not, but if it did, that would explain the error message)